# Replace values from a nested json string column in Spark dataframe

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a nested JSON string as part of a column . I need to replace the keys and values within that deeper JSON with some thing from the map.

I have used typedLit before with a column, but how to use it here.

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val df = Seq(
      ("1", """{"k": "foo", "v": 1.0}""", "some_other_field_1"),
      ("2", """{"p": "bar", "q": 3.0}""", "some_other_field_2"),
      ("3",
        """{"nstKey":[ {"fn":"name1","v1":false,"v2":true},
          |{"fn":"name2","v1":"100","v2":"200"}
          |]}""".stripMargin, "some_other_field_3")

    ).toDF("id", "json", "other")

    df.show(truncate = false)

    val kMap=Map("fn"->"rfn","v1"->"rv1","v2"->"rv2")
    val vmap=Map("name1"->"rename1","name2"->"rename2")

    val df1= df.withColumn("id1",col("id"))
    .withColumn("other1",col("other"))
    .withColumn("k",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.k"))
    .withColumn("v",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.v"))
    .withColumn("p",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.p"))
    .withColumn("q",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.q"))
    .withColumn("nestedKey",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.nstKey"))
    .select("id1","other1","k","v","p","q","nestedKey")
  
  df1.show(truncate = false)
```

result :

```
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id1|other1            |k   |v   |p   |q   |nestedKey                                                                 |
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |some_other_field_1|foo |1.0 |null|null|null                                                                      |
|2  |some_other_field_2|null|null|bar |3.0 |null                                                                      |
|3  |some_other_field_3|null|null|null|null|[{"fn":"name1","v1":500,"v2":true},{"fn":"name2","v1":"abc","v2":"A-1"}]|
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expecting:

```
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id1|other1            |k   |v   |p   |q   |nestedKey                                                                 |
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |some_other_field_1|foo |1.0 |null|null|null                                                                      |
|2  |some_other_field_2|null|null|bar |3.0 |null                                                                      |
|3  |some_other_field_3|null|null|null|null|[{"rfn":"rename1","rv1":500,"rv2":true},{"rfn":"rename2","rv1":"abc","rv2":"A-1"}]|
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` function to replace JSON string values.

```
  val keyChangedDF = kMap.keySet.foldLeft(df1)((df,c)=>
    df.withColumn("nestedKey", regexp_replace('nestedkey, "\""+c+"\":", "\""+kMap(c)+"\":")))

  val valueChangedDF = vMap.keySet.foldLeft(keyChangedDF)((df,c)=>
    df.withColumn("nestedKey", regexp_replace('nestedkey, "\""+c+"\",", "\""+vMap(c)+"\",")))
```

Comment: What is the single quote before nested Key used for?

Comment: That's a syntax sugar. if you `import spark.implicits._` then instead of using `col("nestedKey")` you can use `$"nestedkey"` or `'nestedkey`

Comment: Mohana, The data type of the final nestedKey , how can i convert to Json data type. Its currently string.

Comment: Use `from_json` and pass the JSON schema or if you want to dynamically pass schema use `from_json` with `schema_of_json`. Refer these function usage [here]https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html

Comment: val newDF = valueChangedDF.withColumn("newK", from_json(col("nestedKey"),
    schema_of_json(col("nestedKey")))) ..It is giving error "Schema should be specified in DDL format as a string literal or output of the schema_of_json function instead of schemaofjson"

Comment: I even have tried this ..  val finalDF= valueChangedDF.withColumn("nestedKey", from_json($"nestedKey",
    schema_of_json(valueChangedDF.select(col("nestedKey")).first.getString(0))))

Comment: Both of this 2 :   val sc2= schema_of_json(valueChangedDF.select(col("nestedKey")).first.getString(0))
  val sc1 = schema_of_json(lit(valueChangedDF.select(col("nestedKey")).as[String].first)) return schemaofjson(NULL)

Comment: `nestedKey` column contains null. `get(0)` will give value of 1st row. If it's null then `schema_of_json` will not work. You can say get(//row index where you have JSON). Or you can explicitly pass schema. `new StructType().add() .......`

Comment: The end result coming like [[rename1, false, true], [name2, 100, 200]] . i wanted the same result.    [{"rfn":"rename1","rv1":false,"v2":true},{"rfn":"name2","rv1":"100","v2":"200"}][{"rfn":"rename1","rv1":false,"v2":true},{"rfn":"name2","rv1":"100","v2":"200"}]

Comment: Mohana, i have posted the question here .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021763/dataframe-column-convert-string-json-formatted-to-json-object-data-type-scal . Need your help.