# dataframe column convert string( json formatted) to Json object data type ( Scala)

Tags: json, scala, dataframe

how i can convert a dataFrame column of json string to Json type.
I tried to_json . It does not work .

`[{"rfn":"rename1","rv1":false,"v2":true},{"rfn":"name2","rv1":"100","v2":"200"}]`

```
val sch =
    new ArrayType(

      new StructType()
        .add(StructField("rfn", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("rv1", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("v2", StringType, true)),true)


  val finalDF= myDF.withColumn("nestedKey", from_json($"nestedKey",
    sc3))
```

How ever i am getting a converted result like this
`[[rename1, false, true], [name2, 100, 200]]`

I need the same `[{"rfn":"rename1","rv1":false,"v2":true},{"rfn":"name2","rv1":"100","v2":"200"}]` but not as a **string** , as an json object.

Comment: what is the column type of "newK"?

Comment: updated the question. let me know.

Comment: Whatever you have is JSON object only. There is no Spark-SQL type as JSON.