# replacing json attributes partially in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

**Environment:** I'm using Databricks with spark 3.3.0 and Python 3.

**Problem trying to solve:** I'm trying to replace some of the attribute values of a json struct column. I have a dataframe that contains a struct type column that has the following json content structure:

| ID | myCol |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"att1": "abcde", "att2": "def", "att3": "defg", "att4": "defabc"} |
| 2 | {"att1": "xyfp", "att2": "asdf", "att3": "ertyui", "att4": "asdfg"} |
| 3 | {"att1": "fjhj", "att2": "zxcxzvc", "att3": "wtwert", "att4": "mjgkj"} |

The dataframe contains thousands of records, I'm a bit new to spark programming so I've been having a hard time to come up with a way to replace the values of "att1" and "att3" in all rows in the dataframe with the same value but leaving only the first two characters and masking the rest, i.e from the example above:

Expected Output:

| ID | myCol |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"att1": "ab---", "att2": "def", "att3": "de--", "att4": "defabc"} |
| 2 | {"att1": "xy--", "att2": "asdf", "att3": "er----", "att4": "asdfg"} |
| 3 | {"att1": "fj--", "att2": "zxcxzvc", "att3": "wt----", "att4": "mjgkj"} |

I was looking into maybe using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace` but i don't know how to replace only part of the value, i.e from `"abcde"` to `"ab---"`, i've looked at similar examples online except every single one of them replaces the entire value and the value is known beforehand such as this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/68899109/1994202, however, i need to leave the first two original characters and the value is not static.

Any suggestions? performance would also be important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will help you to select correct characters to replace:

`(?<=..).`

Above means "any character, if it's preceded by two characters. This will not select first or second character, because they are preceded by none/one.

Therefore:

```
df.withColumn("myCol", col("myCol").withField("att1", regexp_replace(col("myCol.att1"), "(?<=..).", "-"))
                                   .withField("att3", regexp_replace(col("myCol.att3"), "(?<=..).", "-"))).show()
```

Comment: worked like a charm!! Also happy to learn about Lookbehind, i've never seen that before, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Full Fledged example using create_map(), based on what @Kombajn zbożowy answered using lookbehind in the regular expression.

1. Create a dataframe as follows using the following schema.

   ```
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    data = [
    (1, {"att1": "abcde", "att2": "def", "att3": "defg", "att4": "defabc"}),
    (2, {"att1": "xyfp", "att2": "asdf", "att3": "ertyui", "att4": "asdfg"}),
    (3, {"att1": "fjhj", "att2": "zxcxzvc", "att3": "wtwert", "att4": "mjgkj"})
    ]

    schema = StructType([
        StructField("ID",IntegerType(), True),
        StructField('myCol', MapType(StringType(),StringType()),True)
    ])


    df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema = schema)
    df.show(truncate=False)
   ```
2. Then use create_map() function to update the json fields of att1 and att3

   ```
    df.withColumn('myCol',create_map
                                    (
                                        lit('att1'),regexp_replace(col("myCol.att1"), "(?<=..).", "-"),
                                        lit('att2'),col("myCol.att2"),
                                        lit('att3'),regexp_replace(col("myCol.att3"), "(?<=..).", "-"),
                                        lit('att4'),col("myCol.att4"),
                                    )
                ).show(truncate=False)
   ```

Find the below picture for your reference:
[image]